# Django ModelForm fields - must have more than one?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a model which has upwards of 25 fields. I want to create a form to edit only ONE of those fields. Thus I did this:

```
class My_Model_Form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = myModel
        fields = ('myField')
```

This gave me errors about `Unknown field(s) (i, b, l, o, T) specified for My_Model_Form`. So, I changed the above to:

```
class My_Model_Form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = myModel
        field = ('myField')
```

(I removed the **s** from `fields`). This worked (as in the `runserver` command runs) however, that form now includes **all** fields from the model `myModel`. The only way I can get my desired one-field form is to use the `exclude` keyword, and list **all fields** except the one I want. This seems ridiculous.

Am I am going at this all wrong. Is there a better/correct way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: are i, b, l, o, and T actual field names on your model?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must have a comma in single-item tuples, otherwise when you iterate over `fields` it will iterate over each character in the string:

```
fields = ('myField',)
```

Comment: See, I knew it was something fantastically simple. Thanks.

Comment: +1, today I solved the exact same problem. Funny is that it makes you puzzle with an anagram instead of keeping the same field order...

Comment: Django makes set of it, so you have pretty random order (not as random as shuffle, but still): set('myField') = set(['e', 'd', 'F', 'i', 'm', 'l', 'y'])